# is + past participle

Tags: aspect

What would be the correct name for the following formula:  is + past participle.  Would this be the present perfect?

An example sentence would be- The meat is stored in the freezer.

Comment: are you sure that this is the place for such a question?

Comment: You might like our sister site, [ell.se].

Answer (score 2):

This example is Present Simple Passive.

Comment: Yes. But.. only if it's generic, and only if it refers to an event and can have a _by_-agent phrase added; _The meat is stored in the freezer by the butcher, but he puts the sausage in the front locker_. If it simply means that the freezer is the location of the meat (with no action implied or referred to), then _stored_ is simply a [Predicate Adjective](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) formed (as many are) from a past participle, and not a product of Passive Formation. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks for the information, I did not know that.

Comment: The meat is stored in the freezer by the butcher, but the baker is kept at room temperature next to the oven.

Comment: Thanks John, you hit the nail on the head.  There is no action implied or referred to.

Comment: The same problem can arise with -ing forms. 'They are flying planes trailing colourful smoke' is obviously ambiguous: is 'flying' part of the verb phrase, or an adjective?