# Is "He is risen" Correct?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, archaicisms, deverbal-adjectives

This is not correct, right? Mixing present tense and past tense makes me think it is not correct but I see it so often on signs that I'm not even sure any more. Is there a specific reason *why* it's often said like that or is it just consistently overlooked?

Comment: No, it's not correct modern English, but it **is** traditional, so we all pretend that's what Aramaic sounds like.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Well, we say bread is risen. And even though the Eucharist may be unleavened, I suppose we could chalk all this up to the miracle of transubstantiation, or fermentation, or one of those -ations.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111268/is-past-participle

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/71012/9368

Comment: And http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4080/now-i-am-become-death-the-destroyer-of-worlds

Comment: It is certainly idiomatic, for English-speaking Christians.

Comment: Intransitive verbs used to form their perfect forms with *to be + past participle*. He is risen; we are fallen; I am come; it is ended; they are departed; she is gone. We still use that last one. In fact, the number of verbs thus conjugated has steadily fallen over the centuries, so that we now use *only* that last one.

Comment: @Anonym Not just intransitive verbs as a category: specific groups of verbs (both transitive and intransitive), especially verbs of motion. _He is farted_ has never worked, for example, but _he is gone the extra mile_ used to.

Comment: @Anonym But the last one has been reanalyzed as an adjectival form.  *She is gone* is fine, but not *\*She is gone to the store*.  When it's used as a verb, it appears in construction with the modern perfect auxiliary *have* instead: *She has gone to the store*.  The perfect auxiliary *be* is well and truly dead in English.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit No, it isn’t. Professor Lawler’s right: it’s an **archaic** present perfect construction now incorrect in current English.  **KJV:** John 3:25 The woman saith unto him, I know that Messias cometh, which is called Christ: when he **is come**, he will tell us all things. 1 Cor 13:1 Though I speak with the tongues of men and of angels, and have not charity, I **am become** as sounding brass, or a tinkling cymbal. Acts 7:34 …I have heard their groaning, and **am come** down to deliver them. Jer 32:2 …The people which **were left** of the sword found grace in the wilderness…

Comment: Comments have been trimmed (and probably could be trimmed more). Comments are intended to elicit further information from the OP or to provide further **relevant** information which the OP may choose to incorporate in the post. They are not for discussion and are certainly not for argument.

Comment: Also cf. Tennyson's "Ulysses", where he writes "I am become a name" rather than the less archaic "I have become a name," and Zelazny's *Trumps of Doom* where he writes "Bye-bye, present tense. I am arrived" rather than "I have arrived." Using this old form of speech is used in both cases to emphasize the present, relevant nature of the thing-which-occurred. Similarly "He is risen" probably persists because Christian culture wants to call attention to the enduring character of Jesus' new heavenly form, and wants to say that it's relevant to you *today* and *now*.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Given that this has appeared around Easter (albeit a couple of days early in my calendar), I'm going to answer on the basis of the phrase

> Christ is risen! He is risen indeed, alleluia!

which is [used in some traditions](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-worship/worship/texts/principal-services/holy-communion/orderone.aspx).

There are two ways of looking at this.

1. It's an archaic use of English which conjugates [verbs of motion with *be* in present perfect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be#be__51), in much the same way as French still does. The statement is the equivalent of "Christ has risen" and is stating a present-perfect fact.
2. It's stating an eternal truth that not only did he rise all those years ago, but he remains risen now. That is, not just "he has risen" but "he **is** risen" and *risen* is closer to being an adjective than a pure participle.

Comment: I am confused.  The use of the present tense of "to be" with the past participle of a verb is still widely used in English today.  One example:  "I am confused".

Comment: But "I am confused" isn't the same present-pefect construction as "He has risen". "He is risen" is a present-perfect construction.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: "He is gone." This is not 'archaic'.

Comment: @WalterMitty: it's not *necessarily* the same construct, because "confused" in "I am confused" is either an adjective derived from a participle ("I am in a state of confusion"), or it's a passive participle ("someone is confusing me: I am confused"). The present-perfect would be "I have confused", meaning "I have confused something or someone". "He is risen" is either a present-perfect (because the person who did the rising is Him), or it's an adjective derived from a participle, in which case it's the same as "I am confused", but to my ear makes Jesus sound like bread.

Comment: As to whether the present-perfect with "to be" is archaic: it's no longer the general rule in common use AFAIK. On encountering a teenager before 10am on a weekend we'd be more likely to say "You've risen early today" than "You're risen early today". I'd speculate that "he is risen" persists in that form precisely because it's known from the King James Bible. The NIV says "he has risen". Of course it's comprehensible and in use, but if a canned phrase whose form is due to an obsolete grammar rule isn't "archaic", then presumably "archaic" is required to mean "not uttered these hundred years".

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit The gone in that case is probably an adjective meaning "Away, having left." as in "Are they gone?" or "Is he gone". Compare to "Are they risen?" and "Is he risen?".

Comment: @WalterMitty Even the 16th-century [Reina Valera Antigua has a *have* + participle form there in Matt 28:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matt+28%3A7&version=RVA), not a *be* + participle form.  Compare the [contemporary NVI](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matt+28%3A7&version=CST).  Spanish stopped using *be* + participle for intransitive verbs of motion even before English did, although both once used them.

Comment: @WalterMitty Well that's fine. This is a site about English. I'm going to clean up some of the comments on this answer, I think.

Comment: It is sometimes true that both native and non-native speakers confuse the apostrophized variants such as "he's gone to the shops" and "he's risen and . . . is now seated at the right hand of the Father " with the auxiliary verb *be* as in: *he is gone* and *he is risen*.

Comment: I ask about the French usage : http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12011/5306

Comment: #2 shouldn’t it at least be, “He is raised?”

Comment: @xr280xr *Raise* is a transitive verb; *rise* is intransitive. So: no.

Comment: As was mentioned earlier, this is indeed an archaic form of English, which one can find in other Germanic languages (e.g., Danish, German) where verbs that indicate motion (e.g., rise, travel, stay, move, etc.) are accompanied by *be* instead of *have*, e.g. "he *is* moved" instead of "he *has* moved".

Answer (score 41):

Affirming Andrew Leach's answer, the [Paschal Greeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschal_greeting) can be classified as a set phrase in many languages--especially those influenced by Orthodox Christianity.

*He is risen* is **perceived** in modern English as a predicate adjective, but it is technically an archaic [present perfect construction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be#be__51) from Matthew 28:6:

> He is not here: for he ***is risen***, as he said. Come, see the place where
>   the Lord lay.
>   *[KJV Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%2028:6-28:7&version=KJV)*
>   ***Emphasis*** mine

The translators of the KJV used this construction to translate the aorist passive ἠγέρθη in the Greek text:

> οὐκ ἔστιν ὧδε, **ἠγέρθη** γὰρ καθὼς εἶπεν: δεῦτε ἴδετε τὸν τόπον
>   ὅπου ἔκειτο:
>   *[qbible.com](http://www.qbible.com/greek-new-testament/matthew/28.html)*
>   ***Emphasis*** mine

The Greek [aorist passive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorist_%28Ancient_Greek%29) has no precise equivalent in English, and this present perfect construction was particularly useful for verbs that presented an ongoing state resulting from a past action like [ἐγείρω](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1453):

> A. to arouse from sleep, to awake
>   B. to arouse from the sleep of
>   death, to recall the dead to life
>   *blueletterbible.org*

Some have tried to parse this as a simple present passive construction, but that is problematic. To distinguish it from the [predicate adjective with a past participle](http://www.english-language-grammar-guide.com/present-participle.html), the *[simple present passive](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html)* normally demands an explicit agent :

> Simple Present
>   *Active* : Once a week, Tom cleans the house.
>   *Passive*: Once a week, the house is cleaned **by Tom**.
>   *englishpage.com*
>   ***Emphasis*** mine

Regardless of the parsing, the expression is designed to **emphasize**--for theological reasons--*the present state of a past action*. Orthodox Christians are taught the preeminence of the historical resurrection of Jesus Christ as the foundation of his ultimate sovereignty and their eternal hope, impregnating the entire antiphonal greeting  with theological significance:

> Christ is risen!
>   He is risen indeed!
>   Alleluia!

Unbelievers can find solace in the fact that this greeting is rarely used outside of the church building.

Comment: "Unbelievers can find solace in the fact that this greeting is rarely used outside of the church building." lol!

Comment: US-specific like so many other answers.

Comment: The King James Version was British English for more than 100 years before the revolution.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Pretty sure the hymn "*Christ the Lord is Risen today*" was written by an Englishman (Charles Wesley), for the English (the Church of  England).  I know I've seen it performed on Easter from Westminster Abbey.  And as far as I know, the greeting phase, like the KJV, originated in England and later spread to the U.S.

Comment: ScotM, @RBarryYoung: Yes, I fully concur. I was referring to the description of this form as "archaic". Perhaps it's archaic in _your_ country!!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit  Not sure about the *form*, but the specific phrase certainly is used seemingly exclusively for this context.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Yeah, granted, this specific phrase.

Comment: Sorry, @LightningRacisinObrit, I was taking my cue from [ODO British & World English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be#be__51), which marked it as archaic. It makes sense that we Americans are more comfortable with that designation. We tend to parse the construction as a predicate adjective by default.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit There is nothing US-specific about any of these answers. Using _be_ to form the perfect of intransitive verbs or verbs of motion **is** archaic, in all forms and dialects of English that I am aware of. _Be_ is now only used with past participles where (a) the sense is passive, or (b) the participle is used as an adjective (“she is gone”; “he is sadly departed”, meaning ‘dead’). In no dialect of English is it common nowadays to say, “We are arrived at King’s Cross” or “The train was already left when I made it to the platform”, for example.

Answer (score 10):

It is correct Early Modern English meaning "He has risen". In older novels one can still find similar sentences, such as "He is come to see you, my Lord."

Present perfect is a phenomenon that emerged in / has spread over many European languages. I believe initially the construction was restricted to certain verbs. In any case, it originally used either *to have* or *to be* as the auxiliary, depending on what made more sense for the (full) verb in question. Examples for this:

- He *has* bought a coat. (He *has* a coat because he bought one.)
- She *has* seen the cat. (She *has* a cat in her mind because she saw one.)
- I *am* gone home. (I *am* home because I went there.)
- He *is* risen. (He *is* upright - or in heaven - because he rose.)

This selection between *to have* and *to be* can still be observed in many (most?) of the European languages that have a present perfect. E.g. in German, Dutch and French (and probably many others), the rule is approximately that *to be* is used for verbs of motion and *to have* for all other verbs. The details differ between these languages (and also between northern and southern speakers of German). *To have* is slowly taking over one after another of the verbs whose present perfect was originally formed with *to be*. English is one of the few languages in which this process has already been completed. See Wikipedia on [Perfect constructions with auxiliaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_%28grammar%29#Perfect_constructions_with_auxiliaries) for details.

(Interesting detail: In some variants of South American Spanish there is a recent development towards using the full verb *tener* instead of the auxiliary *haber*, which can no longer be used to express possession.)

Comment: It’s interesting how English and Spanish started from the same place and went to the same place: that is, from distinguishing perfects with *have* versus *be*, to using only *have*. Although Modern Spanish uses *haber* (to have) for forming perfects, [In Old Spanish, perfect constructions of movement verbs, such as ir (to go) and venir (to come), were formed using the auxiliary verb ser (to be), as in modern Italian and French. For example, *Las mugieres **son llegadas** a Castiella (Las mujeres han llegado a Castilla).*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish_language#Morphology_and_syntax)

Comment: If you read the original text of *El Cantar de mio ÇId*, you can find these old-style present perfects of intransitives being used with *be* not with *have*, just as French and German still use them and as English once did. Furthermore, in that poem they even make participles of active verbs agree in gender and number with a preceding direct object, the same rule which still applies in French and in (northern) Italian.

Comment: Sometimes I find it weird that Portuguese does not have a present perfect -- at least not with the same meaning as in English. Present + past participle in Portuguese should be translated in English as a present perfect continuous... or as present perfect depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @Joseph In portuguese we have an equivalent structure, the Composite Past Perfect, that is exactly the same construction - I have helped him since (...) Eu tenho ajudado ele desde (...). In those constructions, "have" and "tenho" are the same verb (to have/Ter), but the "ter", as all the verbs in portuguese, must be adjusted to the context and becomes "tenho".

Answer (score 3):

It is not contemporary English, as others note in their answers, but mixing present and past tense is not the problem.  There is no past tense in the form.  I suppose you're taking "risen" to be a past participle, and it is, but despite the name, a "past participle" is not past.  It's misleading terminology -- don't let it confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

The past tense (perfect) would be he rose. But this is confirming Jesus' present state of being a risen person.  Therefore in this use I wonder might it not be an adjective.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't refer to an act or a state, but an attribute -- an adjective. The use of phrases like "the risen Christ" confirms that this isn't a on-off special plea.

Comment: No, it is not an adjective.  It is the present perfect.

Comment: It is a past participle employed as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

While the sentence could be taken legal modern English (with the same sentence structure as *He is here*), the real answer is that it is an archaic form.

The King James Version of the Bible consistently uses such language -- for example ["He is come"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/he-is-come-john-168), in John 16:8.

In older English, forms of *to be* rather than forms of *to have* are used, if the verb is a verb of motion. Hence, *he is risen*.

---

This behavior can be traced back to German, the principal ancestor of English grammar.

For example *to eat* is not a verb of motion, and *to travel* is a verb of motion.

- English: *He has eaten.* -- German: *Er **hat** gegessen.* -- Archaic English: *He has eaten.*
- English: *He has traveled.* -- German: *Er **ist** gereist.* -- Archaic English: *He is traveled.*

---

Being a verb of motion can be a tough distinction, with differing opinions and accepted exceptions.  Fortunately, English speakers today don't have to worry about such distinctions.