# Word for reluctance or caution as a result of having already failed?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I'm seeking a word or phrase that conveys a person's heightened caution or risk aversion regarding a task that stems from prior failure. Something like "gun shy," but perhaps more specific?

Comment: I think "gun-shy" is probably about as specific as you can get in a terse phrase.

Comment: *risk averse* or *gun shy*

Answer (score 3):

"Once bitten, twice shy."

"Older and (or but) wiser."

Comment: The 'once bitten, twice shy' saying, apart from being elliptical (not a sentence), uses 'once' in the  'wrong' position. It's in the 'on a previous occasion' position but carries the 'a single time' sense. But 'bitten once ...' just wouldn't sound the same.

Comment: It implies "previous occasion" **and** "single occasion".

Comment: No; the 'bitten' references the past. 'Once there / Once we are there, we can rest' obviously doesn't. //  It's an unusual usage is all that I'm saying. English is awash with them.

Comment: The saying *puns* between the two separate senses of *once.*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Regardless of how "improper" it is, "once bitten, twice shy" is a very familiar idiom in (US) English.  It perhaps comes closest to the OP's desired meaning, but is a bit wordier than some alternatives.

Comment: @Hot Licks I upvoted it. I implied that it was acceptable (But 'bitten once ...' just wouldn't sound the same. //   It's an unusual usage is all that I'm saying. English is awash with them') Unusual in the sense that the positioning of 'once' is idiosyncratic. It's a common usage over here too.

Comment: "It's an unusual usage is all that I'm saying" - Perhaps you're right. Maybe it's synonymous with 'when': "when bitten, shy" or "one we're done, we'll move on". I might not be good at spotting strangeness, because I never studied/learned English grammar, usual or unusual is whatever I've heard in the past (if you know what I mean). For example "[Christ is risen](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237348/9548)" didn't sound a bit unusual to me.

Comment: The phrase also (IMO) implies that the shyness will last twice as long or occur twice as often as the original negative stimulus. ([related example](https://twitter.com/drphil/status/393047687487971329))

Answer (score -1):

Circumspect - Unwilling to take risks as there may be danger involved.

Eg. The batsman was very circumspect in playing deliveries outside off-stump, having got away by edging a few early on in his innings. (You'd hear a lot of this in Cricket commentary.)

Comment: We could also say the batsman was circumspect in his approach given his failure in the previous innings.