# Which is the correct tense to use for this phrase is/was presented with the award?

Tags: tenses

If I am writing the sentence: John is/was presented with an award yesterday.

Which tense should I use? is or was?

How about this? "Please ensure step 1 is completed before proceeding to step 2"

Why "is" is used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only circumstances in which you would use ***is***, would be if you were employing what is known as ***the historical present***.

It is a literary device in which a series of happenings are stated in the present tense even though the reader is aware that it is taking place in the past - e.g.:

*There am I, walking down the street, mindin' me own business, and this chap walks up to me and says, 'Are you my long-lost nephew?'*

[This previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307730/what-is-the-name-for-the-grammatical-figure-where-the-present-tense-is-substitu/307738#307738), on the site will tell you all about it.

Comment: What if it's an on-going, recurring event?  "John is presented with an award for perfect attendance every Friday morning."

Comment: @Scott That is a normal use of the present tense, as it is still happening. The historical present describes past events.

Comment: @WS2 How about this? "Please ensure step 1 is completed before proceeding to step 2"

Comment: @optimus The principal verb is *ensure*, in the imperative mood. The stative verb *is* forms part of the object clause. It relates to a future event, as in *Next year Christmas Day **is** on a Thursday*.

Comment: @WS2 that is why I am using present tense to-be "IS" and past tense for the verb "COMPLETED"? - I still don't quite get it

Comment: @optimus [Have a look at this question - it may help](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111268/is-past-participle)

Answer (score 1):

Past tense since yesterday is in the past.

John was presented...

Comment: If I do not indicate the time?

Comment: You'd still use "was" if the award was presented at any point in history prior to the current moment.